# Subtracting a week from UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM msc_calendar WHERE calendar_userId = 1 AND end < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Is there a way to subtract a week from the timestamp, i.e. to see if `end` was more than a week ago?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@EugenRieck's solution will break on edge cases like weeks where there's a daylight savings switch. It's better to use the built-in function for this, `DATE_SUB`:

```
SELECT * FROM msc_calendar WHERE calendar_userId = 1 AND 'end' < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

Comment: While this solution will break all the time: end is of type int (a Unix timestamp) and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) is of type date. So we need UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))

Comment: Still +1 for pointing out that while a week is allways 7 days (I thought about Feb 29th), but not allways 24*7 hours

Comment: http://science.slashdot.org/story/12/01/05/1453244/leap-second-coming-in-june-2012 just proved @ceejayoz right.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM msc_calendar WHERE calendar_userId = 1 AND 'end' < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-7*24*60*60
```

Comment: Daylight savings will make this glitch in certain weeks, but it doesn't deserve a downvote for that. +1 from me to undo it.

Comment: i only needed to subtract 5 minutes so this method is perfect and faster